# KendoUI Grid custom footer using two or more column with MVC wrapper

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid  and want to use two column to crete a ClientFooterTemplate (Value2).

So, I have :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyGridDto>().Name("grid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Value1)
                       .ClientFooterTemplate("#= sum #");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Value2);
                       .ClientFooterTemplate ( HERE I WANT TO GET SUM OF VALUE3 / SUM VALUE 2)
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Value3).Visible(false);

                  } 
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()  
                      .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                      {
                          aggregates.Add(p => p.Value1).Sum();
                          aggregates.Add(p => p.Value2).Sum();
                          aggregates.Add(p => p.Value3).Sum();
                      })            
                      .Read(read => read.Action("List", "MyController))                      )
 )
```

MyGridDto

```
public class MyGridDto
{
     public decimal Value1 { get; set; }
     public decimal Value2 { get; set; }
     public decimal Value3 { get; set; }         
}
```

I want to show the Value2 footer using sum of Value3 / Sum of Value2. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting the value of the ValueComputed into a temp variable on datasource request end and adding the footer row in as below:

```
 <div class="k-grid k-widget">
    <table class="k-focusable" id="totals" >
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>
                Total price: <span data-bind="text: priceTotal" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Please see the below example for more info:

[Kendo UI Grid With Table Footer by Darren Bell](http://jsfiddle.net/darrenarbell/vzgep/)

You might need to create the Data Source sepearately and will have to bind viewmodel once Data Source is created.

---

**EDIT:**

As per your update, I have created an working sample for your reference using same logic as per the previous table footer example. Please find the working example at below link:

**[Kendo UI Grid Custom Calculated Footer](http://jsfiddle.net/LR59a/3/)**

Do let me know if this is not what you are looking for!

**Edit 2:**

**[Client Footer only](http://jsfiddle.net/9bVB2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question was wrong, so I edited with corrected information. Do you have idea how can I do that?

Comment: Hi @Paul, I have updated the solution and provided a working sample as  per your udpated question. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I already have the footer (created by ClientFooterTemplate) . Its working fine when I´m working with value from just one column. Is there any way to access the sum of other column in ClientFooterTemplate ?

Comment: Ok got it, if that is the case then it is a lot simpler.. You can call any js function to get the values for you. as **footerTemplate: "Your Value: <strong>#= getsumDiv32() # </strong> "**, I have also updated the solution.